# How do you set binary metadata as part of XCode build?

Tags: xcode, build, binary, metadata

I need to set the metadata for binary files which are generated by XCode. For example, fields like "copyright" and "version" which appear in the "Get Info" screen for files.

Is there some way to set a build setting so these properties get set each time the binary is built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **YourProjectName-info.plist** file associated with every xcode project.

This file has lots of project related info including the ones you want as key and values in XML format.

Xcode also gives you option to have a GUI based table like representation of the same.

Read more about it in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/ConfigFiles.html).

**EDIT** :
It seems that the plist is missing from command line projects by default.
Read [this](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2083/the-power-of-plist) post  which explains the fundamentals of plist nicely.

Read **Embedding Info.plist** section in it to know about how to do it in command line project.

Comment: I checked several of my projects (which are all command line projects) and none of them have the Info.plist file. Is the file hidden or do I have to do something special to create it myself? The apple documentation says it should be created automatically when I make a project, but for some reason it wasn't.

Comment: I found a sample UI project which had the XXX-Info.plist file you mention, and that binary has proper metadata based on the plist. However when I added the same type of plist file to my command line project with the same properties, none of them worked. Is the plist only supported by UI apps?

Comment: Ya , I just checked, people have complained about it that the file is missing from command line projects. 
I will check more and get back to  you.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try out the method the article methods (adding a special section), but it looks like it is just what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get the "Bundle versions string, short" version to reflect in the output binary as "Version", but when I use "Copyright (human-readable)" it doesn't effect the binary's meta data. Is there some other key I need to use for Copyright? I tried searching in the apple system binaries but can't find a binary with embedded copyright information, is this supported at all?

Comment: NSHumanReadableCopyright is the key as per apple's documentation.

checkout http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html